# GitHub commit with "invalid email"

Tags: git, commit

I need to change the author's email of old commits on Github. I found a script on GitHub that allows to change the author email from old (wrong one) to new  [article link](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)
, but in my case,I don't know what email did I use to push the commits. So is there anyway to find out the "invalid email" and correct it? . On the blue circle (as per screenshot) asking me to correct my email on GitHub which is correct but how could that resolve the issue for old commits? Any help would be much appreciated.
[[image: Screen shot[2]]

Comment: Regardless of whether you find out who made the commits, you should realize that in order to add an email to those commits, you will need to rewrite the history of the branch.  This can have some undesirable side effects, so you carefully consider if you want to really do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the far right side you can see the commit hash used for the commit in question. Use

```
$ git show <commit>
```

and look at the **Author** line. There you should see a **name** and an **email address**.

---

Keep in mind, that rewriting those commits with the new email address will rewrite the history of every commit from there on (because the parent hashes will change too).